# Search recursively for a string containing whitespaces

Tags: linux, search, grep, string, whitespace

I want to search for "this table..." string under `/home/myuser` directory recursively, ie in all files under `/home/myuser` and in all directories and sub-directories under `/home/myuser`.

`/home/myuser` directory is set to a environment variable: `$MYUSR`

The search must be case insensitive, and it should give me the full path name of the files containing "this table..." string.

I try:

```
grep -R "this table..." $MYUSR
```

but I'm not sure if it really searches because I wait for a long time and it does not return any result and it never ends.

I also want to know how to do the same search recursively in the directory I'm standing in, maybe like:

```
grep -R "this table..." .
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  find $MYUSR -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i -l 'this table...'
```

The options to `find` are

- `-type f`    - we don't want to search directories (just files in them), devices etc
- `-print0`    - we want to be able to handle filenames containing spaces

The options to `xargs` are

- `-0`         - Because of find -print0
- `-n 10`      - Run grep on 10 files at a time (useful when not using grep's `-l`)

The options to grep are

- `-i`          - ignore case
- `-l`          - just list filenames (not all matching lines)
- `-f`          - treat dots in search expression as plain ol' dots.

To start in the current directory replace `$MYUSR` with `.`

---

Update (a fellow superuserer suggested `find -type f -exec grep -i "this table..." +`)

```
$ ls -1
2011
2011 East
2011 North
2011 South
2012


$ find -type f -exec grep -i 'this table...'
find: missing argument to `-exec'

$ find -type f -exec grep -i 'this table...' +
find: missing argument to `-exec'

$ find -type f -exec grep -i 'this table...' {} \;
this table... is heavy
THIS TABLE... is important
this table... is mine
this table... is all alike
this table... is twisty
```

But that's not useful, you want filenames

```
$ find -type f -exec grep -i -l 'this table...' {} \;
./2011 East
./2011
./2011 North
./2011 South
./2012
```

OK but often you want to see the matching line content too

If you want filenames AND matching line content, I do it this way:

```
$ find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 grep -i 'this table...';
./2011 East:this table... is heavy
./2011:THIS TABLE... is important
./2011 North:this table... is mine
./2011 South:this table... is all alike
./2012:this table... is twisty
```

But without "old skool" `-print0` and `-0` you'll get a mess

```
$ find -type f | xargs -n 10 grep -i 'this table...';
./2011:THIS TABLE... is important
grep: East: No such file or directory
./2011:THIS TABLE... is important
./2011:THIS TABLE... is important
grep: North: No such file or directory
./2011:THIS TABLE... is important
grep: South: No such file or directory
./2012:this table... is twisty
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of `10` ?

Comment: And How do I make the same search i the directory im standing in?

Comment: @alwbtc: See updated answer

Comment: No need all of this old school tricks : `find -type f -exec grep -i "this table..." +` is sufficient.

Comment: @sputnick: on my system, find complains: *"find: missing argument to '-exec'"* unless you add `{} \;` also you need grep's `-l` option otherwise it doesn't show filenames. If you want to see matches AND filenames you probably need xargs in the mix (or some equivalent options)

Comment: Thanks, you are searching for `foo`, but you didn't use double quotes. What would you do in above examples if you searched for "this table.." which contains whitespaces?

Comment: @alwbtc: Sigh ... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What should I do to bind `find -type f -exec grep -i -l 'this table...' {} \;` to an alias? for example, when I do `mysearch "this table..."` it should be equal to `find -type f -exec grep -i -l 'this table...' {} \;` ? Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the size of the directory and subdirectorys where you search. But `ack` will better fits your needs. See http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: So, `grep -R "this table..." $MYUSR`is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but add `-i` switch : case insensitive